# Meaning of "consumer presence"

Tags: meaning

I don't understand the meaning of "consumer presence" in the following quotation, and I couldn't find the phrase "consumer presence" defined anywhere.

> For any new table reservations product, no matter how good it is, it’s very hard to get businesses to adopt the product at scale for two reasons. First, it is hard to scale a sales team without massive funding. Secondly, it is hard to sell the product if you don’t have a significant **consumer presence**.

Comment: It's another way of saying *user base* or *audience base* I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression you probably need to use is ***[customer base](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/customer-base.html)***:

> - The clients to whom a business sells products and services. The customer base is a relatively broad number of customers, with a smaller section of the base being comprised of repeat customers.

(www.businessdictionary.com)

*Consumer presence* is not a common  expression and could be open to different interpretations. Google books yields zero results for 'consumer presence'.